# Using Brownie to verify contract error

Tags: solidity, etherscan, brownie, sepolia

I added sepolia with my infura api key to deploy my contract it works fine. Until I try to verify my contract with `publish_source=True` in `FundMe.deploy` function:

```
 from brownie import FundMe

 from scripts.helpful_scripts import get_account 

 def deploy_FundMe():

    account = get_account()
    fund_me = FundMe.deploy({"from": account}, publish_source=True)
    print(f"Contract deployed to {fund_me.address}")

def main():
    deploy_FundMe()
```

**Error:**

```
  File "D:\python3_10\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\run.py", line 51, in main
    return_value, frame = run(

  File "D:\python3_10\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\scripts.py", line 110, in run
    return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)

  File ".\scripts\deploy.py", line 12, in main
    deploy_FundMe()

  File ".\scripts\deploy.py", line 7, in deploy_FundMe
    fund_me = FundMe.deploy({"from": account}, publish_source=True)

  File "D:\python3_10\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\contract.py", line 549, in __call__
    return tx["from"].deploy(

  File "D:\python3_10\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\account.py", line 557, in deploy
    contract.publish_source(deployed_contract, silent=silent)

  File "D:\python3_10\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\contract.py", line 408, in publish_source
    data = response.json()

  File "D:\python3_10\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 975, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)
```

Comment: Did you export your api ehtherscan token in your .env file?
export ETHERSCAN_TOKEN=<token>